# Issue while connecting to Cassandra running in docker from Spring boot application

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

**application.properties: **

```
    spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
    spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=oboe
    spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=cassandra
    spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
    spring.data.cassandra.username=cassandra
    spring.data.cassandra.password=cassandra
    spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
    spring.data.cassandra.entity-base-package=com.example.cassandra.connectivity
```

**Error while starting Spring applciation: **

```
2022-10-06 23:55:34.844  WARN 3284 --- [     s0-admin-1] c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection    : [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=cassandra/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=68e4631), trying next node (UnknownHostException: No such host is known (cassandra))
2022-10-06 23:55:36.980  WARN 3284 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scanLocationDataController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scanLocationDataService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scanLocationDataRepo' defined in org.gcs.cassandra.repo.ScanLocationDataRepo defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/gcs/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/gcs/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/gcs/cassandra/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=cassandra/<unresolved>:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=68e4631): [java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (cassandra)]
```

**Docker Container logs: **

```
cassandra 21:35:51.97 INFO  ==> ** Starting Cassandra setup **
cassandra 21:35:51.98 WARN  ==> CASSANDRA_HOST not set, defaulting to system hostname
cassandra 21:35:51.98 INFO  ==> Validating settings in CASSANDRA_* env vars..
cassandra 21:35:51.99 WARN  ==> You've not provided a password. Default password "cassandra" will be used. For safety reasons, please provide a secure password in a production environment.
cassandra 21:35:51.99 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra. This is the default value when bootstrapping Cassandra and should not be used in production environments.
cassandra 21:35:52.01 INFO  ==> Initializing Cassandra database...
cassandra 21:35:52.21 INFO  ==> Deploying Cassandra from scratch
cassandra 21:35:52.22 INFO  ==> Starting Cassandra
cassandra 21:35:52.22 INFO  ==> Checking that it started up correctly
cassandra 21:36:57.30 INFO  ==> Found CQL startup log line
cassandra 21:36:58.74 INFO  ==> Nodetool reported the successful startup of Cassandra
cassandra 21:36:58.75 INFO  ==> Non-seeder node. Waiting for synchronization
cassandra 21:36:58.75 INFO  ==> Trying to access CQL server @ ccff4fe7e189
cassandra 21:37:11.24 INFO  ==> Accessed CQL server successfully
cassandra 21:37:11.25 INFO  ==> ** Cassandra setup finished! **
```